# How to read from env in Windows in c++

Tags: c++, windows, api, directory

I want to get system folder in windows, by reading SystemRoot.
How can I do it? 
many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read the environment variables, use [getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28VS.71%29.aspx) or [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

However, if you want to find the `%SYSTEMROOT%` directory consider using [GetWindowsFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454%28VS.85%29.aspx)

---

For other special folders, you can use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx) or [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a windows API you should use instead: [GetWindowsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454%28VS.85%29.aspx)

But if you do want to read from the environment you can use [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), or from the C runtime with [getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28VS.80%29.aspx) or even get the environment pointer from the unofficial third main argument `int main(argc, argv, envp)` which is supported by the VC runtime.

Comment: +1 for good answer and the Microsoft '3rd argument to main' extension - it's always nice to learn something new.

Comment: It's not just Microsoft - pretty much everything does have envp. GNU Make relies on it even and that's supposed to just work out-of-the-box everywhere. The only system I've ever seen without it was Interix 2 (3+ has it though) and there's an exception in GNU Make for AmigaOS too I think.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly easy with GetEnvironmentVariable():

```
DWORD WINAPI GetEnvironmentVariable(
  __in_opt   LPCTSTR lpName,
  __out_opt  LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  __in       DWORD nSize
);
```

See MSDN on [GetEnvironmentVariable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more infos and some examples (the function is used in Example 2)